# Assign increasing index per group in grouped dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataframe/tibble that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
      id date      
   <int> <date>    
 1     1 1998-02-13
 2     1 1998-02-14
 3     1 1998-02-15
 4     1 1998-02-16
 5     1 1998-02-17
 6     2 1998-02-13
 7     2 1998-02-14
 8     2 1998-02-15
 9     2 1998-02-16
10     2 1998-02-17
11     3 1998-02-13
12     3 1998-02-14
13     3 1998-02-15
14     3 1998-02-16
15     3 1998-02-17
```

I would like to add a variable "days_before_event" that would count from 1:5 (but this should not be hardcoded and rather be the elments per group). I though about doing something like this

```
df_long %>% mutate(days_before_event = 1:nrow(.))
```

where `nrow(.)` should be the the number of rows per group. This does not work and shows the error

```
Fehler: Problem with `mutate()` input `days_before_event`.
x Input `days_before_event` can't be recycled to size 5.
i Input `days_before_event` is `1:nrow(.)`.
i Input `days_before_event` must be size 5 or 1, not 15.
i The error occurred in group 1: id = 1.
```

Any trick on how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `row_number` instead of `1:nrow`

```
library(dplyr)
df_long %>% 
    mutate(days_before_event =row_number())
```

---

Or using `base R`, use `ave` to group over the 'id' and get the sequence (`seq_along`)

```
df_long$days_before_event <- with(df_long, ave(seq_along(id),
          id, FUN = seq_along))
```

---

The error is because it is a grouped dataset (from the group attribute showed in the printed data), therefore, 1:nrow will get the sequence from 1st to the last row of the entire dataset and not the last row of the group.  This creates an imbalance in `length` and `mutate` can return only the output having the same `length` as the original data (or else have to wrap in a `list`)

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot!! If I would want to use base r, you know how I could achieve the same goal?

Comment: oh wow, thank you so much! Base r directly looks way more intimidating haha

Comment: @RobinKohrs In data.table, it is much more compact `setDT(df_long)[, days_before_event := rowid(id)]`

Comment: thaks a lot! I never really considered data.table as I'm not really working with large datasets. I thought one would give up easier sytax for faster processing. But maybe it is worth looking more into it:)